# Getting median from an array of frequencies?

Tags: java, arrays, math

I have an array which for example in `array[1]` will contain however many times one occurred in a list of numbers, likewise `array[2]` will be however many twos there were.

This is what I have tried so far

```
    int tot = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        tot += array[i];
    }
    int mid = tot/2;
    int med = array[mid];
    return med;
```

This doesn't work, and I feel like there's a lot more calculations that I haven't done.
Any guidance is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you need to find the index where you have seen the "middle":

```
int tot = 0;
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    tot += array[i];
}
int mid = tot/2;
int med = 0;
tot = 0;
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    tot += array[i];
    if(tot >= mid) { 
        med = i; 
        break; 
    }
}

return med;
```

**Update:**
As Ajay Reddy stated in the comments, above code is only correct for an uneven length of the array. For even length, there is an upper and lower median, the average of which is the actual median. If you actually want that depends on what you are doing afterwards with the median (if it needs to actually occur use above code, it finds the lower median).

```
int tot = 0;
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    tot += array[i];
}
float mid = tot/2;
int upper_med = 0;
int lower_med = 0;
tot = 0;
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    tot += array[i];
    if(i > 0 && array[i-1] > 0) {
        lower_med = i;
    }
    if(tot >= mid) { 
        upper_med = i; 
        break; 
    }
}

return array.length % 2 == 0 ? (float)(upper_med + lower_med)/2 : lower_med; // cast to float or not according to your requirements
```

Comment: The index of mid shouldn't be `(tot+1)/2`?

Comment: @OhadEytan No, for example if the array is [500,1,1], the median is clearly 1, but tot is 502.

Comment: I think I didn't understand your example. If you have 500 zeros so the median is clearly 0.

Comment: Lets say the array of numbers is [2 2 3 5 6 7].....the frequency array will be [0 0 2 1 0 1 1 1] ......using your program we get the median as 3...but the correct median is (3+5)/2 = 4

Comment: @AjayReddy Hmm ok I wasn't aware that  if the amount of numbers is even, the median is the average between the two middle numbers. It seems easy enough to fix though, just keep track of the last non-zero occurence and change mid to float. I might edit later.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the index of the initial array that has the midpoint of the total frequencies.

I'd calculate the rolling frequency totals and then do a `>` check for the rolling frequency that is the first one that is bigger than the midpoint. Something like this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    /* Number   Frequency
     *      0           5
     *      1           6
     *      2           8
     *      3           1
     *      4           2
     *      5           3
     *      6           6
     *      7           9
     *      8           5
     *      9           7
     * 
     * Total = 52
     *                       Midpoint(s)
     *                          **
     * 0000011111122222222344555666666777777777888889999999
     * 
     * Median = 6
     */
    final int[] frequencies = {5,6,8,1,2,3,6,9,5,7};
    final int[] rollingFrequencies = new int[frequencies.length];

    rollingFrequencies[0] = frequencies[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < rollingFrequencies.length; i++) {
        rollingFrequencies[i] = frequencies[i] + rollingFrequencies[i-1];
    }

    //At this point, rollingFrequencies is: [5, 11, 19, 20, 22, 25, 31, 40, 45, 52]
    final int total = rollingFrequencies[rollingFrequencies.length - 1]; //The final rollingFreq will be the total.
    final int mid = total / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < rollingFrequencies.length; i++) {
        if( rollingFrequencies[i] > mid ) {
            System.out.println( i );
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sort, find the index of the middle, in case of even number take the mean of two elements around the middle -- why rolling stuff?

Comment: @OlegS. I'm rolling stuff because the array contains the frequencies, not the actual values. Your method works if the array has the actual list pof numbers, but it doesn't. The OP stated the array is of the frequencies of each number, so you need to find the index that occurs at the midpoint of the total number of frequencies, hence why I've found the rolling frequency totals. The comment in my code snippet explains what the initial array represents and how you'd find the median using your method with the given frequencies of digits.

Comment: Fair enough, the question could have been more clearly formulated. I'll bump it up again

Answer (score -1):

Quting from wikipedia ...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median

The median of a finite list of numbers can be found by arranging all the observations from lowest value to highest value and picking the middle one (e.g., the median of {3, 3, 5, 9, 11} is 5). If there is an even number of observations, then there is no single middle value; the median is then usually defined to be the mean of the two middle values (the median of {3, 5, 7, 9} is (5 + 7) / 2 = 6), [...].

Comment: Quoting from Wikipedia doesn't really explain why OP's code doesn't work right.  Why does OP's code not do what Wikipedia says he needs to do?