# Find the median of a stream of ages

Tags: java, algorithm

Recently, I was given a coding question where the statement was that **I would be given a stream of ages of people and then at any point the median would be asked for.**

Something like this:

```
add(20)
add(30)
add(30)
add(40)
getMedian() // prints 30
```

Now this problem is similar to this Leetcode problem:

[Find Median from Data Stream](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-median-from-data-stream/)

So I gave the 2 heaps approach - **one max heap and one min heap**.

The interviewer was not impressed and hinted that there **was an optimization possible since all the ages of people could be assumed to be between** `1 to 130`, **and also there would be a lot of repeated ages** ie. there are a lot of people with the age 20, for example.

I was unable to come up with any better optimizations, so I gave an approach with a `HashMap` counting all the frequencies and then counting the occurances. This was completely incorrect.

What am I missing here ? **How does the ages being bounded help me ?**

EDIT:

Answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23603511/7134737

Comment: One trivial thing to do with absolute bounds is just use an array for the counts, i.e. `int [] counts = new int[130]; .. count[age]++ ..`

Comment: @karakfa Wait, so my `HashMap` approach was right ?

Comment: *"right"* in the sense that it will work, but not optimal if that's what they are after.

Comment: HashMap is overkill for a problem which only needs an array.

Comment: @karakfa Yes but I was on the right track, correct ?

Comment: @pjs But it would work right ?

Comment: @ng.newbie it will work but don't forget that real purpose of the interview is not to get a solution for the question but evaluate your problem solving skills.  Insisting on a suboptimal solution is not going to cut it just because it works.

Comment: @karakfa I get that. But I had to come up with this on the spot. So I guess I was "half-right".

Comment: I think your original heaps approach was pretty solid, especially on unbounded input.

Comment: @Neil Thanks. But unfortunately the interviewer was not impressed with and asked for greater optimization since the input was bounded between a range.

Answer (score 1):

The approach that the interviewer was probably looking for is this.

Maintain an array of frequency counts.

Maintain the overall count of the array.

Maintain a variable saying which bucket the median value is in, and a second where in that bucket it is.

Inserts are `O(1)` because you have to update an array entry, update the overall count, update where in that median bucket you are, and occasionally scan through a fixed number of buckets for the next one with entries.

Returning the median is `O(1)` as well because you are maintaining that answer in a variable that you can look up.

Using a HashMap instead of an array is just constant factor different.  However having to calculate the answer on demand is slower.

Note that this answer is optimized for the median.  Suppose that we wanted to calculate any particular percentile instead.  We can make that easy with a different data structure.

---

I would solve this one with a 257 element array arranged like this:

```
0: 0
1: Count of people aged 0
2: Count of people aged 0 or 1
3: Count of people aged 2
4: Count of people aged 0, 1, 2, or 3
5: Count of people aged 4
6: Count of people aged 4 or 5
7: Count of people aged 6
8: Count of people aged 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, or 7
...
```

In general the `2^i * j`th entry, with `j` odd, will be the count of people in the range `2^i * (j-1)` to `2^i * j - 1`.

To insert a value, I start at `n+1` and jump to increasing powers of 2 for a maximum of 8 entries.  For example if I have a 21 year old to insert in the data structure, I would increment the values at 22, 24, 32, 64, 125, and 256.

To get a count of people who are less than or equal to 21 I similarly look down by powers of 2.  So I'd read the values at 22, 20, 16 and 0.

To get the total people in the data structure, I'd look at the value in position 256.

To find what age a specific count falls at is more complicated.  I'd fall down by powers of 2 then do a binary search.  So suppose that the final answer was 21.  I'd have had to look at 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, and then locked in the age range 0..15.  Then look for the 16..31 year olds by looking in 24 then 20.  That locks in the 16..19 year olds.  Repeat with 22, 21 and lock in the 20 year olds.  And my answer is somewhere in the 21 year olds.

In the given example this data structure is `O(1)` for all operations because it has fixed size.  But if you had a larger number of buckets, then all operations are `O(log(# of buckets))`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, but I am unable to understand the logic of how your solution works. **Firstly**, I don't know why you structured the array the way that you did, why is `1` containing the count of people of age `0` ? Why is `6` containing the count of ages `4` and `5`, why is `8` containing the count of ages between `0` to `7` ? **Secondly**, what are `i` and `j` ? **Thirdly**, how will all this help me calculate the median ? **Can you please add some more detail here ?** I guess I lack the mathematical prerequisite.

Comment: Also why take a **257** element array ?

Comment: @ng.newbie 257 because I wanted element 256 to be there and we start at 0.  It was easier for me to reason about.  But forget the second approach, the first is what they were looking for.

Comment: As for the second approach, the idea is to record data over ranges of size a power of 2, so we can find how many are in any given range really quickly.

Comment: I thought that this was one single approach - what do you mean by the first approach ?

Comment: If you meant by first approach where you have to maintain a variable for which bucket contains the median - then my question to you is that **what do you mean by bucket ?** How does a frequency count help me to work with **buckets** ? We just have an array of frequency counts. I think I am missing the intuition here.

Comment: @ng.newbie By bucket I mean "age bucket".  The same approach that here is being used for "years old" can also be used for "miliseconds to respond to API".

Comment: How would you solve this - 1,2,40,45 ? How do I maintain a variable to the median when the median is actually the average between 2 and 40 ? And while entering the data by the `add()` function how do I identify in constant time that the median is `2` and `40` ? **I would have to loop over the entire array every time some thing is added right ?**

Comment: How does maintaining a `count` variable help me ? What will be the count for this - `40,40,40,40` will it be `4` or will it be `1`, since only `1` age has been added multiple times ?

Comment: It will be 4 because you've got 4 people of age 40.  And no, you don't have to loop over the whole array every time, you just have to know which side of the median the new value is.

Comment: I think I got the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23603511/7134737

Comment: I think the only question is that do I need the loop every time while calculating the median ? Lets say I have **1,2,20,45**, the median is `avg(2,20)`, so I know from `4/2 = 2`, but I will still have to loop over the array and find the occurrence where I get `2`.